# how to make a good deployment with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-play-services

I hope you are well, I have a problem for a while I implement google authentication in my application flutter everything works normally but when I deploy the application on playstore all features work except authentication with google

no error is this product

Comment: you will need to update your project's SHA keys in Firebase and google json in your project.